# Having trouble with engraving cursive text, where only a couple letters are being removed. How do you think I can fix this?

Tags: text-object, boolean-modifier

Let me preface this by saying that I'm still very new to Blender, so I don't know all the tricks and terms.

So I am following along with this YouTube tutorial to engrave text in a mesh in my model. I followed along, but ran into the following problem.

After going through the Decimate Modifier step in the tutorial, I noticed that there were a couple locations (both ds, the s, and the A) where there are lines crossing over the letter. I don't know what this means, but it looks like it's the shortest length between two points on the letter connecting with one another, crossing over the letter to do so rather than the next point on the "outline" of the letter.

[image: Wireframe view of text]

After the applying the Boolean Modifier Step, the surface I am trying to subtract material from immediately looks like it does below.

[image: Text Object after Boolean Modifier operation completed]

Then when I hide the text mesh, the surface looks like it does below.

[image: Remaining model when text object is removed]

As shown above, something funky happened. It looks like the operation worked for the two letters at the beginning and the end ("Ed and WA"), but the weirdness occurred in the middle, and I'm not exactly sure what happened. I have a suspicion that this may be happening because the text is cursive because I've done something similar with a serif font before and it worked. But yeah, I have no idea what's going on here/why it's not working.

Do any of you have an idea of what might be going wrong, or what I could try to do to fix this? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please add a link to the tutorial you are following into your question. It would also help if you could share your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: If you provide the file on Blender-exchange you will get a more concrete answer but in this case it's probably the topology of the text not being great. Try adding a Remesh modifier to the text object. Set it to Sharp mode and uncheck the 'Remove disconnected' option. Increase the Depth until you get all the letters well defined before using it in the boolean. The lines on those letters you mention are just there because they need to connect the hole on the inside to the outside, they are most likely not the issue

Comment: Other things that can help booleans work is going into edit mode, selecing all vertices and merging them by distance (M->By distance) so that overlaping vertices get fixed. Also selecting all faces and pressing Shift+N to recalculate the normals. Do this on both objects if they have complex geometry